# MATLAB: Error in for loop for index

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, indexing

I would like to separate the following identity matrix's column

```
I =
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
```

using for loop and then label it as an indexed vector.
then I used

```
n=3;
I = eye(n);
for i = drange(1:n)
    e(i) = zeros(n,1)
end
```

to generate column vectors for the final step:

```
for i = drange(1:n)
    e(i)= I(:,i)
end
```

But I have error for the indices. is anyone knows how to get ride of?

or in general, how I could separate columns of a matrix to separate vectors with some indices that have to use this vectors?

Comment: I cannot understand the question. What are you trying to do? Please give an example of resulting matrix `e` you want. Currently you are trying to assign a vector to a single element that produce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate directly

```
n=3;

e=eye(n,n);
```

By the way, you can correct the loop using:

```
for i=1:n
   e(:,i)=I(:,i); 

end
```

However, there is no need for it!

Comment: Thanks. but my problem is not creating the identity matrix, rather is to separate it as vectors indexed by the position of 1 in every column of I.

Comment: I do not understand! do you want to do something like v=I(:,1), getting the first column of I?

Comment: Yes exactly I meant the columns not the first one but all of them and inside a loop with indices. Because I will have more than 10000 columns and will call some of them later on code.

Comment: You can access any column of I any time you want... You do not need to separate it in different vectors. You have just to vary the index as in the second part of the answer above...